# Xubuntu GUI not loading?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, vnc, amazon-ec2, xubuntu

I just installed xubuntu-core on my amazon-ec2 server, but I can't get it to load into a UI. When I try to use `sudo startx` it throws an error, while `sudo service lightdm start` doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried rebooting the instance to no avail.

For reference, I'm trying to load the UI using an installation of TigerVNC, which seems to be working fine (I can connect to the virtual desktop, except it still loads as a command prompt).

How can get the GUI to show up?